# Contact form module 

Tags: drupal, drupal-forms, drupal-contact-form

I'm a beginner, and I try to use the Contact module, but it restricts users at least for an hour to send second post. Is there a way to overcome this limitation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think You can change it in the admin contact settings (about link: admin/build/contact/settings ?).

Comment: Yup - there is a setting in there for "Hourly threshold"

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 6, when you enable the Contact module, you see the "Hourly threshold" option in admin/build/contact/settings.

[image: screenshot]

In Drupal 7, that option doesn't exist anymore; there is only the option top enable the personal contact form by default, in admin/config/people/accounts.

[image: screenshot]